# Python bubble chart that shows frequency or weight of bubble (I don't have a z vector)?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I want to make a scatterplot of two categorical variables (both are 0 and 1), but when I make a normal scatterplot in python there are only four dots of the same size. All I have is a pandas data frame with two columns (A and B) each full of 0s and 1s.

https://pypi.org/project/bubble-plot/

I ran something like the example in the above link

```
bubble_plot(df, x = 'A', y = 'B')
```

And I think it gave me what I want, but I have no idea how to get a legend showing what the size or colors mean.

Any idea on how to get a bubble plot with a legend?

Thank you!

Comment: can you show what your df looks like ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there are only four dots of the same size

Well, in your specific case both the x- and y-Values contain only `[0,1,1,0,..]`, so the `bubble_plot()` can only show you bubbles positioned at `[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]`. The different sizes give you the correlation of columns 'A' and 'B', i.e. the size of the bubble at `[1,0]` shows in how many rows there was a `1` in column 'A' and a `0` in column 'B'.

If you add a `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and `plt.colorbar()`, you'll be able to see that the colours mean the same as the sizes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bubble_plot.bubble_plot import bubble_plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(2020)

A = np.random.choice([0,1],size=50)
B = np.random.choice([0,1],size=50)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':A, 'B':B})

bubble_plot(df, x='A', y='B')

plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

And if you were to use `h = plt.hist2d(df['A'], df['B'], bins=2)` instead of the `bubble_plot()`, you could use `print(h[0])` to get the distribution information:

```
[[13. 15.]
 [14.  8.]]
```

or, normalised `print(h[0]/h[0].sum())`:

```
[[0.26 0.3 ]
 [0.28 0.16]]
```

i.e. in 16% of the dataset a `1` in `df['A']` correlates with a `0` in `df['B']`.